# Configure AWS-AppSync for production with Apollo-client

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, react-native, apollo-client, aws-appsync

I am not able to get my app working in production mode. It is working fine in development. I am testing the API which is called right after the splash screen. The app is stuck on splash screen in production.

As for the configuration part, these are all I have used:

In client.ts file:

```
const link = ApolloLink.from([
  createAuthLink({
    url:'https://myapi.appsync-api.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/graphql',
  region:'ap-northeast-1',
  auth:{
    type:'API_KEY',
    apiKey:'keyyyyy'
  }
  }),
  createHttpLink({ uri: `https://myapi.appsync-api.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/graphql` }),
]);

export const client = new ApolloClient({
  link,
  cache,
});
```

In app.tsx file:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Platform } from 'react-native';
import { SafeAreaProvider } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
import { ApolloProvider } from '@apollo/client';
import { client } from './graphql/client';
import { StorageProvider } from './helpers';
import AppNavigator from './navigation/AppNavigator';
import { AppearanceProvider, ThemeProvider } from './theme';
import { ModalProvider, PostProvider, UserEventProvider } from './utils';

if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
  require('intl');
  require('intl/locale-data/jsonp/en-US');
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
      <StorageProvider>
        <SafeAreaProvider>
          <AppearanceProvider>
            <ThemeProvider>
              <PostProvider>
                <ModalProvider>
                  <UserEventProvider>
                    <AppNavigator />
                  </UserEventProvider>
                </ModalProvider>
              </PostProvider>
            </ThemeProvider>
          </AppearanceProvider>
        </SafeAreaProvider>
      </StorageProvider>
    </ApolloProvider>
  );
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Am I missing any other configuration step?

Comment: This is likely a deployment issue (possibly network configuration). You could debug this by opening your graphql endpoint on a browser with introspection turned on. Then you could verify that your endpoint is up and hit it with queries.

Comment: And how do I do that? I've been going through thia link: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/appsync-graphiql-local/ , it tells that index.js file should be created with a certain code. Is that necessary to get the graphql running?

Comment: By the way, I tried sending the incorrect API key, the data wasn't being able to fetch until I used the correct API key  in my code above.

Comment: If that's the case I recommend deleting the question since it was just a misconfiguration.

Comment: I need someone to help me w the configuration.

Comment: Then you'll need to ask a question where you discuss your configuration and what might be wrong with it.

Comment: There are a few things that could be causing this issue. First, make sure that you have set up your production environment correctly. This includes setting up your production URL and ensuring that your production API key is correctly configured. Secondly, make sure that you are not using a self-signed SSL certificate for your production environment. Finally, make sure that you have correctly configured your production build settings.